# python: I want to modify the value of one complex dictionary using kv pairs, how to implement?

Tags: python, dictionary

For example, the dict is:

`dict1={'a':1, 'b':[{'b1':21, 'b2':21, 'b3':31}, {'b4':41, 'b5':61, 'b6':61}], 'c':3}`

I have one function `f1()`:

```
def f1(dictionary, kv):
    modify k = v
```

If I want to modify `b5=51` like:

```
f1(dict1, b5=51)
```

How can implement the function `f1`?

Comment: What if there are several b5?

Comment: My answer assumes you want to set `b5` *at the top level*. If you want to *search* the structure recursively to find the same key *in a nested level* you need to state so explicitly in your question.

Comment: if the key in every level, maybe they are not unique and cannot find the correct one, i want to transfer this information using the kv arguments, like "b[1]['b5']=51

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `kv` a `**` capturing argument, then use `dict.update()` to pass all captured key-value pairs on to the dictionary:

```
def f1(self, dictionary, **kv):
    dictionary.update(kv)
```

Demo (with the `self` argument omitted to make `f1` a function):

```
>>> dict1={'a':1, 'b':[{'b1':21, 'b2':21, 'b3':31}, {'b4':41, 'b5':61, 'b6':61}], 'c':3}
>>> def f1(dictionary, **kv):
...     dictionary.update(kv)
...
>>> f1(dict1, b5=51)
>>> dict1
{'a': 1, 'b5': 51, 'c': 3, 'b': [{'b1': 21, 'b2': 21, 'b3': 31}, {'b4': 41, 'b5': 61, 'b6': 61}]}
```

This updates key-values *at the top level of the dictionary*.

If you need to search for matching keys, use recursion and dictionary views. This is a Python 2 version:

```
def f1(self, obj, **kv):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        for value in obj:
            self.f1(value, **kv)
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        for key in kv.viewkeys() & obj.viewkeys():
            obj[key] = kv[key]
        for value in obj.itervalues():
            self.f1(value, **kv)
```

and a Python 3 version:

```
def f1(self, obj, **kv):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        for value in obj:
            self.f1(value, **kv)
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        for key in kv.keys() & obj.keys():
            obj[key] = kv[key]
        for value in obj.values():
            self.f1(value, **kv)
```

Demo on Python 2, again with `self` removed:

```
>>> def f1(obj, **kv):
...     if isinstance(obj, list):
...         for value in obj:
...             f1(value, **kv)
...     elif isinstance(obj, dict):
...         for key in kv.viewkeys() & obj.viewkeys():
...             obj[key] = kv[key]
...         for value in obj.itervalues():
...             f1(value, **kv)
...
>>> f1(dict1, b5=51)
>>> dict1
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': [{'b1': 21, 'b2': 21, 'b3': 31}, {'b4': 41, 'b5': 51, 'b6': 61}]}
```

Comment: You and your advance "recursion" fix my question perfectly! Thank you very much!